# soapUI: property not used in property expansion in a test case

Tags: properties, soapui, expansion

I'm using soapUI 3.6.1 and I want to test a SOAP-interface with a test structure like this:

```
MyWorkspace
    MyProject
        TestSuite
            TestCase Single
                TestStep 1
            TestCase Loop
                Properties #1
                Groovy #1
                Run TestCase Single
                Properties #2
                Groovy #2
                Run TestCase Single
```

`TestCase Single` contains a bunch of requests that should be performed with the same account-id. `TestCase Loop` is supposed to call `TestCase Single` using different account-ids. The `Properties *` are supposed to change the account-id.

`MyProject` has a property `accountId` set up with value 1234. This should work as the default value for single testing of the test cases, i.e. `TestCase Single`.

`Properties #1` and `Properties #2` have `accountId` specified with different values.

The intention is to allow `TestStep 1` to be executed alone or as part of `TestCase Loop`.

`TestStep 1` has a common SOAP-body where the following is a parameter sent to the web-service:

```
     <accId>${='${#accountId}' != '' ? '${#accountId}' : ${#Project#accountId}}</accId>
```

`Groovy #1` and `Groovy #2` look like this:

```
log.info('Using account ' + (context.expand('${#accountId}') != '' ? context.expand('${#accountId}') : context.expand('${#Project#accountId}')));
```

My problem now is that the Groovy-script writes the correct value of `accountId` (i.e., the one inside the loop), but the `TestStep 1` always uses the value from the project. I want `TestStep 1` to use the value of the loop.

For debugging purposes I also put the following into `TestStep 1`:

```
<!--
{#Project#accountId}: ${#Project#accountId}
{#TestSuite#accountId}: ${#TestSuite#accountId}
{#TestRunContext#accountId}: ${#TestRunContext#accountId}
{#TestRun#accountId}: ${#TestRun#accountId}
{#TestCase#accountId}: ${#TestCase#accountId}
{#TestStep#accountId}: ${#TestStep#accountId}
{#MockService#accountId}: ${#MockService#accountId}
{#Global#accountId}: ${#Global#accountId}
{#System#accountId}: ${#System#accountId}
{#Env#accountId}: ${#Env#accountId}
{#accountId}: ${#accountId}
context.accountId: ${=context.accountId}
modelItem.accountId: ${=modelItem.accountId}
request.accountId: ${=request.accountId}
context.expand(): ${=context.expand('${#accountId}')}
-->
```

I traced the network traffic with Wireshark and noticed that only `${#Project#accountId}` returned a value.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I need to code the `<accId>`-element to send the correct value to the remote host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I revisited this issue and I think I found the best possible solution, even though I don't understand why my initial attempt didn't work.

I changed the structure to this:

```
MyWorkspace
    MyProject
        TestSuite
            TestCase Single
                TestStep 1
            TestCase Loop
                Groovy #1
                Run TestCase Single
                Groovy #2
                Run TestCase Single
```

In other words I got rid of the `Properties` and moved the logic into the `Groovies`:

```
context.getTestCase().getTestSuite().setPropertyValue("accountId_loop", "1720");
```

and the appropriate line in `TestStep 1`:

```
     <accId>${='${#TestSuite#accountId_loop}' != '' ? '${#TestSuite#accountId_loop}' : ${#MyProject#accountId}}</accId>
```